# box shadow animation is instead changing the size

Tags: css, reactjs

--- EDIT 2 ----

Here is another example video, if the issue and how strange it acts within my react application. Once again, I have no idea how to pin point the issue

[Issue in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrGox.jpg)

---

I have a div with a class name `side-btn`

It has an animation that isn't behaving how I thought and I'm not sure why. The animation is simple for a box shadow change:

```
.side-btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-colour: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 black;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 black;
  }
  70% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px 20px black;
  }
  100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 black;
  }
}


<div class="side-btn"></div>
```

I was following this [pulse animation](https://codepen.io/igorsheg/pen/MBpwGw)

Within this code snipit, it behaves as expected. I'm using this within a reactJS application. I use this within my js application and this exact css, it behaves completely differently. The box just grows insize and shrinks. There is no other pulse animation. I'm having trouble recreating this bug as well.

```
function Sidebar(props) {
  return (
    <nav className = {"sidebar" + (props.active ? "" : " hidden")}>
      <div class="side-btn"></div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

I inspected the element and it just seems as if the div side is just growing and shrinking in size. I'm not even sure how to debug this.

-- EDIT:

I've created a code sandbox, and using overflow's code snip-its and they work as expected. Again, once I put into my react app, I get this result. I made a short clip to show. I cannot pin point why this is happening.

The only different code I have added is that the side-btn is wrapped in a 'sidebar' container which just centers it and puts it off screen a bit.

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top:50vh;
  left:-35px;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoKW8.jpg

Comment: i think your code is working. just change the `box-shadow` to `50% transparent black` so that you can see the effect. use `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` for `box-shadow`. the box is not resizing. but the `box-shadow` that you set makes you feel that the box is resizing :)

Comment: @Zuber I attempted your fix as well, it doesn't work still strangly. I've added more to my answer to explain the issue more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify shadow color's alpha, to achieve the fading effect.

So, instead of using `black` you should use `rgba(0,0,0,1)` and `rgba(0,0,0,0)`:

```css
.side-btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-colour: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 black;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
  }
  70% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="side-btn"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is changing the box shadow and not the size of the box. If you look closely perhaps you'll notice. You can see that the size of the div remains same. Just the shadow expands and contracts. In your example above, the blur and spread area where high ( blur being comparatively low ) so it looked like it was getting a border around it rather than a box shadow. For making it clear, run the snippet below which is similar to yours :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.side-btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  }
  70% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side-btn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added more to my answer, it doesn't behave as it does within this snippet.

Comment: Updated it according to the example. I think this will do.

Comment: stragly, it still doesnt work. I have posted another example video with the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you updated the code properly with the code I gave in the answer?

Comment: Note that we also need to change opacity while animating the shadow so that it fades aways while expanding.

Comment: I checked the video link, looks like you have white shadow on a white box. Maybe change the color of the div a little to see what's happening? If you have both box and the shadow of the same color then it will look like it is expanding ( if opacity is not altered while animating ).